# Error when reloading new Plugin code in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qtplugin

I am nooby to Plugin Development but I'm trying to create a plugin in QGIS, for a Uni-subject, with its own graphical interface, which will receive a zipcode from the user and return the name of the corresponding location.

I already created the plugin skeleton, through the Plugin Builder and have designed the graphical interface with QtDesigner https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6k6Q.png . I also added the .txt file that contains the zipcodes database to the plugin folder as a resource.

From what I understand, the file to edit is the one that ends in dialog.py, through the **init**() method, in order to establish the connections between the signals emitted by the elements of the graphical interface and the corresponding callbacks.

However, when I change the code in the dialog.py and reload the plugin, it gives me an error, and when starting the QGIS it pop-ups an error message, and the plugin no longer appears. [Error message after plugin reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRVkC.png)

Could you give me some guidance here and maybe point me to where the problem could be? Thanks

The code is this one:

```
import os
import sys

import qgis.core
from qgis.PyQt import uic
from qgis.PyQt import (
QtCore,
QtWidgets
)

import geocoder

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(
    os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__),
        "example_dialog_base.ui"
    ),
    resource_suffix=""
)

class ExampleDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    POSTAL_CODES_PATH = ":/plugins/example/todos_cp.txt"

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
    """Constructor."""
    super(ExampleDialog, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
    # connect signals
    self.postal_code_le.textChanged.connect(self.toggle_find_button)
    self.find_code_btn.clicked.connect(self.execute)
    # set initial state
    self.find_code_btn.setEnabled(False)

    def toggle_find_button(self):
        if self.postal_code_le.text() == "":
            self.find_code_btn.setEnabled(False)
        else:
            self.find_code_btn.setEnabled(True)

    def execute(self):
        self.address_te.clear()
        try:
            raw_postal_code = self.postal_code_le.text()
            main_code, extension = validate_postal_code(raw_postal_code)
            record = self.find_record(main_code, extension)
            place_name = record[3]
            self.address_te.setPlainText(place_name)
            if self.create_layer_chb.isChecked():
                self.handle_layer_creation(record)
        except (ValueError, RuntimeError) as err:
            self.show_error(str(err))

    def find_record(self, main_code, extension):
        file_handler = QtCore.QFile(self.POSTAL_CODES_PATH)
        file_handler.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
        stream = QtCore.QTextStream(file_handler)
        while not stream.atEnd():
            line = stream.readLine()
            info = line.split(";")
            code1 = info[-3]
            code2 = info[-2]
            if code1 == main_code and code2 == extension:
                result = info
                break
        else:
            raise RuntimeError("Sem resultados")
        return result

    def handle_layer_creation(self, record):
        place_name = record[3]
        point = geocode_place_name(place_name)
        print("lon: {} - lat: {}".format(point.x(), point.y()))
        layer = create_point_layer(
            point,
            f"found_location_for_{record[-3]}_{record[-2]}",
            place_name
        )
        current_project = qgis.core.QgsProject.instance()
        current_project.addMapLayer(layer)

    def show_error(self, message):
        message_bar = self.iface.messageBar()
        message_bar.pushMessage("Error", message, level=message_bar.Critical)

    def validate_postal_code(raw_postal_code):
        code1, code2 = raw_postal_code.partition("-")[::2]
        if code1 == "" or code2 == "":
            raise ValueError(
                "Incorrect postal code: {!r}".format(raw_postal_code))
        return code1, code2

    def geocode_place_name(place_name):
        geocoder_object = geocoder.osm(place_name)
        lon = geocoder_object.json.get("lng")
        lat = geocoder_object.json.get("lat")
        if lat is None or lon is None:
            raise RuntimeError(
                "Could not retrieve lon/lat for "
                "place: {!r}".format(place_name)
            )
        point = qgis.core.QgsPointXY(lon, lat)
        return point

        def create_point_layer(point, layer_name, place_name):
            layer = qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer(
                "Point?crs=epsg:4326&field=address:string(100)",
                layer_name,
                "memory"
            )
            provider = layer.dataProvider()
            geometry = qgis.core.QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(point)
            feature = qgis.core.QgsFeature()
            feature.setGeometry(geometry)
            feature.setAttributes([place_name])
            provider.addFeatures([feature])
            layer.updateExtents()
        return layer
```

Comment: Expected indentation on line 26 in `example_dialog.py`. You may want to change the settings of your editor to see all whitespace characters and check your file.

Comment: Actually it is already obvious in your posted code. There is no indentation of your `__init__` function's code block.